# Enabling a minor mode in all but some buffers

Tags: minor-mode

I want to enable `display-line-numbers-mode` in all buffers except pdf
buffers.  Can I do that without making a list of all the major modes
except pdf-view mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substitute `my-pdf-mode-hook` for whichever major-mode that should be excluded.

```lisp
(global-display-line-numbers-mode t)

(add-hook 'my-pdf-mode-hook (lambda () (display-line-numbers-mode -1)))
```